# Is there any way to link a data set from another sheet to a chart in google sheet?

Tags: charts, google-sheets

I have used column charts to create a report using Google sheet. Can I do something so that clicking on the particular column will show some details about the data set of that column?

Comment: could use a [tooltip column](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#tooltiprole)...

Comment: can you elaborate?